# Can I embed a local image on a Google Map?

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-maps-api-3

I am leveraging Google Maps API from Delphi 10 Seattle.

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
  begin
    aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
      aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit)
        .Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
    finally
      freeandnil(aStream);
    end;
    HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
  end;

  fContainer := TExternalContainer.Create(WebBrowser1);
end;
```

This allows me to make JavaScript calls into the Map JS using an instance of IHtmlDocument2 interface.

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnStartPointClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('EmbedImageAtLatLng(%s,%s, %s)',[edtLat.Text,edtLon.Text, edtImageName.txt]), 'JavaScript');
end;
```

My client would like me to post a specific image at a specific location for use by his workers.  Is this possible.

Note:  this image is a local image and not served.  It is simply passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Not in a straight way, at least to my knowledge. But what you *can* do is make use of [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) to upload your image and make it available to the workers.

PS: I mentioned Google Drive so you make use of the same Google account you have for Google Maps, but you could use any other content manager.

Comment: Actually, I was able to pass a bmp in the straight way.  It just took a little massaging.
Thanks

Comment: That's great @MetaMussel! Would you share your solution? At least the part where you "inject" your image to GMaps. I tried [adding a custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) setting a base64 encoded image as the source image. I tried other options as well, all of them implementing a base64 enconded image instead of an URI. But I don't like the fact that the size of a base64  encoded image increases its size to 30% (or more) compared to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I went with an info window.

```
marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({    
 content: "<div class= ''map-overlay'', style = ''width:110x; height:74px''; float: left><img align=''Left'' src= ''C:/Scripts/QRCode.bmp''></div>"   
    });
```